# Parallel while loop with unknown number of calls

Tags: python, while-loop, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have written a function that does some calculations, and that everytime it is called it returns a different result, since it uses a different seed for the random number generator. In general, I want to run this functions many times, in order to obtain many samples.

I have managed to use `multiprocessing` to run this function in parallel, using, for example, 4 processes, until the desired number of runs `n_runs` is reached. Here is a minimal working example (note that the function `flip_coin()` is just an example function that uses a `rng`, in reality I am using a more complex function):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random, sys

def flip_coin(n):    
    # initialise the random number generator
    seed = random.randrange(sys.maxsize)
    rng = random.Random(seed)
    # do stuff and obtain result
    if rng.random()>0.5: res = 1
    else: res = 0
    return res, seed

# total number of runs
n_runs = 100
# initialise parallel pool
pool = mp.Pool(processes = 4)
# initialise empty lists for results
results, seeds = [], []
for result in pool.map(flip_coin, range(n_runs)):
    # save result and the seed that generated that result
    results.append(result[0])
    seeds.append(result[1])
# close parallel pool
pool.close(); pool.join()
```

Now, instead of fixing the `n_runs` a priori, I would like to fix a different condition that is met only after an unknown number of calls to the function. For example, I would like to fix the number of `1`'s returned by the function. Without using `multiprocessing`, I would do something like this:

```
# desired number of ones
n_ones = 10
# counter to keep track of the ones
counter = 0
# empty list for seeds
seeds = []
while counter < n_ones:
    result = flip_coin(1)
    # if we got a 1, increase counter and save seed
    if result[0] == 1: 
        counter += 1
        seeds.append(result[1])
```

The question is: how do I parallelise such a `while` loop?

Comment: `n` is not used in your `flip_coin(n)` - why do you need it there?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Otherwise `pool.map(flip_coin, range(n_runs))` does not work. I know, there's probably a cleaner way, but this works and that's ok for me.

Comment: paralleling in not an option in your case cause you need to analyze each function call to decide to terminate processing. Technically you can just spawn 1000 (or whatever number of) threads, or processes or coroutines beforehand  and block each unit to check if shared counter of `1`s is reached 10, but that's incorrect design and bad approach.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Come on, there must be a way!

Comment: No, the best you can apply is spawning at most `n_ones` parallel units at a time, analyze them, then - spawning next `n_ones` threads/processes if counter is not reached

Comment: I question whether this would even benefit by using multiprocessing since `flip_run` does not appear to be that CPU-intensive. Have you timed your current code and compared it with a serial implementation?

Comment: @Booboo That's just an example... my real function is much more CPU-intensive!

Comment: previous comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75832731/parallel-while-loop-with-unknown-number-of-calls#comment133764080_75832731 can be your solution, try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment concerning whether multiprocessing is even advantageous. But this is how I would do it. The idea is that once you have been returned enough 1 values, you (implicitly) call `terminate` on the pool:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import random, sys

def flip_coin(n):
    # initialise the random number generator
    seed = random.randrange(sys.maxsize)
    rng = random.Random(seed)
    # do stuff and obtain result
    if rng.random()>0.5: res = 1
    else: res = 0
    return res, seed

def main():
    def generate_run_numbers():
        # An inifnite supply:
        n = 0
        while True:
            n += 1
            yield n

    n_ones = 10
    counter = 0
    results, seeds = [], []
    with mp.Pool(processes = 4) as pool:
        for res, seed in pool.imap_unordered(flip_coin, generate_run_numbers()):
            results.append(res)
            seeds.append(seed)
            if res == 1:
                counter += 1
                if counter == n_ones:
                    break
    # This results in a call to pool.terminate(), which
    # kills all pool processes and no more tasks will be processed
    print(len(results), 'invocations were required.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
16 invocations were required.
```

Another way is to use method `apply_async` with a callback. Here we use a semaphore to throttle task submission so with a given `POOL_SIZE` value there will never be more than `POOL_SIZE` tasks sitting on the task queue waiting to be executed. In this way we do not execute more tasks than necessary and when a pool process finishes execution of a task it will not remain idle since there will always be a task sitting on the queue waiting to run.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import random, sys
from threading import BoundedSemaphore

def flip_coin():
    # initialise the random number generator
    seed = random.randrange(sys.maxsize)
    rng = random.Random(seed)
    # do stuff and obtain result
    if rng.random()>0.5: res = 1
    else: res = 0
    return res, seed

def main():
    def callback(return_value):
        nonlocal counter, stop

        semaphore.release()
        if not stop:
            res, seed = return_value
            results.append(res)
            seeds.append(seed)
            if res == 1:
                counter += 1
                if counter == n_ones:
                    stop = True

    POOL_SIZE = 4
    # Always have one POOL_SIZE tasks sitting in the task queue for each pool process so
    # when a pool process completes a submitted task there is always one
    # queued up task it can immedaitely run:
    stop = False
    semaphore = BoundedSemaphore(2 * POOL_SIZE)
    n_ones = 10
    counter = 0
    results, seeds = [], []
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = POOL_SIZE)
    while not stop:
        semaphore.acquire()
        pool.apply_async(flip_coin, callback=callback)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(f'{len(results)} invocations were required.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, I did something in the line of your first method. What would be the advantage of the second method?

Comment: There is no real big advantage other than the pool’s task queue  will never grow that large. That would only matter if what was being placed on the queue was very large and memory is small.